# auto-select on workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup in VSCode

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Is it possible to send an argument, or make a setting, in VSCode so that using the named function always selects the first match without confirm?

I want to rebind to another key than Ctrl-tab (leader + key in VSCodeVim to be specific), and when I do it seems that I have to confirm the switch with Enter whenever I use it.

Answer (score 1):

I could bind it this way:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    // Switch recently used editor.
    {
        "before": ["<leader>", ","],
        "commands": ["workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup", "list.select"]
    }
]
```

Hope it helps.